# From left to right window animation with react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is there a way to implement animation that goes from left to right with navigate() function in react-navigation ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I think it is possible. checkout this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/views/transitioner

Comment: I checked it out but it is really confusing. My navigate function is like this:
<Button onPress={()=> navigate('Question',{id: question.id})}> And i want this to navigate from left to right animation. Could you please explain more ? @Awa

Answer (score 2):

Answered by [satya164](https://github.com/satya164) in react-navigation/stack github repo, using `gestureDirection: 'horizontal-inverted'` in `defaultNavigationOptions/navigationOptions`

```
Screen: {
  screen: Screen,
  navigationOptions: {
    ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS,
    gestureDirection: 'horizontal-inverted',
  },
},
```

related links below:

https://github.com/react-navigation/stack/issues/377#issuecomment-578504696

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#animation-related-options

Answer (score 0):

when you define your screens, you can use `transitionConfig` option.

```
const Stack = StackNavigator(
  {
    SomeScreen: { screen: ... },
  },
  {
    transitionConfig: customAnimationFunc,
  }
);
...

import CardStackStyleInterpolator from 'react-navigation/src/views/CardStack/CardStackStyleInterpolator';

const customAnimationFunc = () => ({
  screenInterpolator: sceneProps => {
    return CardStackStyleInterpolator.forVertical(sceneProps);
  },
});
```

should do the job. You can of course define your own animation, or return null to disable it; check the sources for that.

Comment: so how should i arrange my navigate function after implementing all of these bro ?

Comment: you will use the navigate function without any adjustment, the animation will be taken care of

Comment: is there a way to implement this to only one screen ?

Comment: how do I implement from bottom to top in iOS? tried .forHorizontal or forFadeFromBottomAndroid but doesnt work. still left to right

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I also struggled to find a config that did this for only one screen at a time and ended up using [react-navigation-transitions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-navigation-transitions).

```
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {fromLeft, fromRight} from 'react-navigation-transitions';
import {ScreenA, ScreenB, ScreenC} from 'screens'; 

export const handleCustomTransition = ({scenes}) => {
  const prevScene = scenes[scenes.length - 2];
  const nextScene = scenes[scenes.length - 1];

  if (
    prevScene &&
    prevScene.route.routeName === 'ScreenA' &&
    nextScene.route.routeName === 'ScreenB'
  ) {
    return fromLeft();
  } else if (
    prevScene &&
    prevScene.route.routeName === 'ScreenA' &&
    nextScene.route.routeName === 'ScreenC'
  ) {
    return fromRight();
  }
};

const stack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    ScreenA: homeScreen,
    ScreenB: messageScreen,
    ScreenC: settingsScreen,
  },
  {
    transitionConfig: nav => handleCustomTransition(nav),
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

animation property on RootStack Navigator takes different values

```
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack'

const RootStack = createNativeStackNavigator()
return (
   <RootStack.Navigator
       screenOptions={{headerShown: false, animation: 'slide_from_right'}}>
     // Your Screens Here
   </RootStack.Navigator>
)
```