# How to stop default transition when using custom tab bar in React Native using React Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I've made a custom tab bar in a Component which uses `StackNavigator` like so

```
export default StackNavigator(
  {
    Login: {
      screen: Login,
    },
    ForgotPassword: {
      screen: ForgotPassword,
    },
    SignUp: {
      screen: SignUp,
    },
    Home: {
      screen: Home,
    },
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
    navigationOptions: {
      headerVisible: false,
    },
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  },
);
```

Now my `Home` screen has a custom made Tab Bar like so

```
export default () => (
  <View>
    <Text>HOME</Text>
    <TabBar />
  </View>
)
```

I want my `Home` screens Tab bar to have no transition

Currently it animates (`left to right` for `IOS` & `bottom to up` for `Android`) when one of the Tab link is clicked

I checked docs & found `mode` property but it has only 2 props `card` & `modal` & I want no animation

How to do it ?

Comment: As I understood from code, your `Home` screen has a tab bar with 4 tabs. But it's unclear for me, what transitions you want to disable?

Comment: Yep u are right. When I am on 1 tab & click another there is left to right transition on IOS bcz I've set it up in `StackNavigator`. I want to have no transition

Comment: so you want to have no animation? Because no transition means - another tab won't be opened :)

Comment: Yep no animation, thanks edited question

Comment: I think, it is not possible to change animations at the moment using react-navigation. For more info, have a look here (https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/175). This library was mentioned in the issue - https://github.com/wix/react-native-interactable (unfortunately never used it). You can follow another issue for updates regarding your problem - https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/2585.

Comment: @AkshayKadam check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46625311/2070942 - when you return null, animation will be disabled

Comment: @VojtechNovak what to return for default animations. Right now nothing is animating. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Vojtech, I got the answer

```
const customAnimationFunc = () => ({
  screenInterpolator: (sceneProps) => {
      const { scene } = sceneProps;
      const tabs = ['Home'];
      if (tabs.indexOf(scene.route.routeName) !== -1) return null;
    },
});

export default StackNavigator(
  {
    Login: {
      screen: Login,
    },
    ForgotPassword: {
      screen: ForgotPassword,
    },
    SignUp: {
      screen: SignUp,
    },
    Home: {
      screen: Home,
    },
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
    transitionConfig: customAnimationFunc,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerVisible: false,
    },
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  },
);
```

The only problem right now is nothing is animating. I'll edit the answer when few screens animate & tabs don't