# Filtering intermediate screens in StackNavigator state

Tags: react-navigation

I use react-navigation with react-navigation-redux-helpers.

And let's say i have a stackNavigator with such a state:

```
{
  index: 2,
  routes: [route1, route2, route3]
}
```

In some moment I need to filter out route2:

```
{
  index: 1,
  routes: [route1, route3]
}
```

If I do this with NavigationActions.reset, it will be animated like i opened route3 again.

Is there any way to filter route from StackNavigator state without any animation?

More illustrated description:

I have difficult checkout flow and some of it's screens depends on user logged in. For checkout navigator user can be logged in at any moment (because auth can be showed in another modal StackNavigator). So i can not use NavigationActions.replace when I open route3.

I'm also interested in opposite situation: when I have to push route2.1 in state.

Answer (score 0):

to the best of my knowledge, react-navigation in v1 only allows to set up animations on a per-router basis, as seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46625311/2070942) answer.

based on `sceneProps`, you'll need to figure out the condition that covers your use case and return null for no animation. This interface may improve in v2, judging from [the sources](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/2e47cbb3cbbae267cfa184ac02da0e8a5e7c27d6/src/NavigationActions.js#L24).

Comment: Thanks! I'll try v2 then