# Left and right navigation with React Navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

For the life of me I am unable to figure this out; I have a React Native app that does some authentication on a splash screen, and then navigates to a landing page. The landing page (middle) has a screen to the left and to the right.

Navigating to the right works just fine using this.props.navigation.navigate('RouteName'). However, when I navigate to the left screen, it still slides in from the right. Is there any way to override this behavior?

```html
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Splash: {screen: Splash, navigationOptions:navConfig},
    middleScreen: {screen: Middle, navigationOptions:navConfig},
    LeftScreen: {screen: Left, navigationOptions:navConfig},
    RightScreen: {screen: Right, navigationOptions:navConfig},
  })
```

Is it just not loading all the scenes onto the stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @Giacomo Cerquone's suggestion, I resolved the majority of issues I was facing here.

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
    index: 1,
    actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Left'}),
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Middle' }), // Index 1 selects this one
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Right' }),
  ],
});

this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but you've got an intuitive definition for the sliding direction animation completely wrong. It doesn't work like that, the order in which you define your routes has completely nothing to do with the animation with which these routes are animated.

Going further, your request is pretty common and in this stackoverflow question you can find the answer you're looking for: [From left to right window animation with react-navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46624633/from-left-to-right-window-animation-with-react-navigation)

Comment: Thanks for your response - I figured as much. I checked out the linked post, but that solution no longer works since CardStackStyleInterpolator is no longer packaged with newer versions of react navigation.

Comment: @Make-HCI well you can always define your animation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/transitioner.html

Comment: Actually there would be some dirty method too that I wouldn't recommend. When you navigate you could use a reset action that rebuilds the stack where on top of it there is the screen you want to navigate to using a right to left animation, and behind that you put all the routes you want to access with an animation from left to right, and then, to navigate, you call pop!

It's so silly they didn't integrate it. I faced a lot of problems (now solved thanks to v2) in the past with this lib, and the maintainer there aren't nice: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2390

Comment: Yea I'm just gonna do a Reset action and order them to get the right animations when navigating and using PopTo. Crazy that this is the mess required to get something basic like that working. Thanks!

Comment: @Make-HCI please, mark the question as resolved if so :)